# php form does not write into database using MVC

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop

I am trying to create a blog using php in a MVC architecture.
My **database** looks like this:

```
TABLE `blog_posts` (
    `post_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_name` VARCHAR(64),
    `post_title` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `post_desc` TEXT,
    `post_cont` TEXT,
    `post_date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
 FOREIGN KEY (`user_name`) REFERENCES users (`user_name`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Now, I am trying to create a blogpost and I just cannot figure out why it is not working.
I am just getting my default values in my database not the once I write into the form.
Here is **my code**:
**Controller**

```
/**
 * Creates a new blogpost. This is the target of form submit action.
 */
public function create()
{
    if (!empty($_POST['post_title']) AND !empty($_POST['post_desc']) AND !empty($_POST['post_cont']) AND isset($_POST['post_cont'])) {
        $note_model = $this->loadModel('Blog');
        $note_model->create($_POST['post_title'] AND $_POST['post_desc'] AND $_POST['post_cont']);
    }
    header('location: ' . URL . 'blog');
}
```

**Model**

```
    /**
     * Setter for a blogpost (create)
     * @param string $post_cont blogpost text that will be created
     * @return bool feedback (was the post created properly ?)
     */
    public function create($post_title, $post_desc, $post_cont)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO blog_posts (post_title, post_desc, post_cont, user_name) VALUES (:post_title, :post_desc, :post_cont, :user_name)";
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':post_title' => $post_title, ':post_desc' => $post_desc, ':post_cont' => $post_cont, ':user_name' => $_SESSION['user_name']));

        $count =  $query->rowCount();
        if ($count == 1) {
            $_SESSION["feedback_positive"][] = FEEDBACK_BLOGPOST_CREATION_SUCCESSFUL;
            return true;
        } else {
            $_SESSION["feedback_negative"][] = FEEDBACK_BLOGPOST_CREATION_FAILED;
        }
        // default return
        return false;
    }
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo URL;?>blog/create">
        <label>Title: </label><input type="text" name="post_title" />
        <label>Description: </label><input type="text" name="post_desc" />
        <label>Blogpost: </label><textarea name="post_cont"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value='create blogpost' autocomplete="off" />
    </form>
```

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated! Thank you!!

Comment: Arguments to the function passed using comma, not `AND`

Comment: Check the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@u_mulder have right.

You have to use this call like this :

```
$note_model->create($_POST['post_title'], $_POST['post_desc'], $_POST['post_cont']);
```